# Are users on iPhone 5 (iOS 10) able to see new apps on the App Store?

Tags: ios, applications, apple-store

We're an app developer and want to ask if iPhone 5 users (who cannot upgrade to iOS 11) are able to see newer apps or updated apps on the App Store that has been made 64-bit compliant.

- Can they see these apps on the app store?
- Can they install these apps?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the actual problem you are facing here? Are these apps still installable on iOS10, are they 32 or 64bit, did you move an app from 32bit to 64bit and are now wondering what a user with iOS10 will see in the store?

Comment: Is this specific enough?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer from iOS 12's perspective for apps which need iOS 13 to work. I cannot reach the app page via search feature. But given direct link, it opens the app page and shows the banner about incompatibility.

[iMovie for iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id377298193) is one example. Searching doesn't list this.

[image]